# Как получить id из php массива с помощью JS?

Tags: php, javascript, массивы

У меня есть задача, получить ID элементов и php массива с дальнейшим применением в коде JS.
есть 2 массива:

```
echo '<input class="choose_check" id="cc_'.$i.'" name="check[]" type="checkbox" value=""></input>';
echo '<input class="choose_check_url" id="cc_url_'.$i.'" name="check[]" value="" type="checkbox" ></input>';
```

эти массивы имеют динамические ID, в чем собственно и есть моя проблема.
И JS код, который работает в этом же файле.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("cc_0").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.getElementById("cc_0").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
function mouseOver() { 
   document.getElementById("cc_url_0").checked = true; 
}
function mouseOut() { 
   document.getElementById("cc_url_0").checked = false; 
}
</script>
```

Для примера я поставил статичные ID массивов, но мне нужно прикрутить к JS коду возможность работать с динамическими ID.
Пожалуйста, кому не сложно подскажите как реализовать.
Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: заодно загуглите про data-параметры